# How do I upload an image using FTP with Objective-C? (mac app, not iOS)

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion

Does anyone know if there's a built in method/object I can use or an existing library? I have the host, post, username, password, path to the image (local) and destination path (remote). The sever suports 'sftp' and 'ftp', I don't think I can upload via http.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy. CFFTPSample (P.S. or it was SimpleFTPSample?) - demo app from XCode documentation. Run it, it does exactly you ask for.

Or read an article: [Working with FTP Servers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFFTPTasks/CFFTPTasks.html)

Comment: +1. It's CFFTPSample (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CFFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html). It's a bit out of date—but if Xcode 4.3.2 can open, convert, build, and run the sample successfully, and it doesn't use any deprecated APIs, that's not a problem. And as far as I know, there's still no higher-level (ObjC) alternative (unlike for downloading, where NSURLConnection does the trick), so this is the best answer for what the OP wanted.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks for helping. I'm getting the following error when I try to run the sample on Xcode 4.3.2: "The scheme 'CFFTPSample' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination My Mac 64-bit. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode." Here's a picture: http://cl.ly/1t3d1n2H0C1M1N3b0b0J I tried changing "Deployment Target" from "Mac OSX 10.4" to every possible option (default, 10.7, 10.6, 10.5). No dice. I'm running 10.7.3. Any ideas what's wrong (beside the sample being a bit old)?

Comment: "Deployment Target" isn't the problem, it's "Base SDK", so you're changing the wrong value. You can just change the right one and it'll work. But a better idea is to go to the Issue Navigator and work from the bottom up—first click on the one that does Project Cleanup and pick the defaults, then click on the Target Integrity one and it'll take you to the right line in Build Settings (change it to Latest Mac OS X), and then go through the Format String Issues and let Fix-It do what it suggests for each one, and you should be done.

Comment: PS, if you plan to do this in multiple projects (or multiple places in one project), I'd consider wrapping up all of this logic in a new ObjC class or a category on NSURLConnection or something like that, rather than directly calling CF methods all over the place.